# Save nvd3 charts as a SVG file

Tags: svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

I was wondering how to extract/download a svg file from a chart generated with nvd3.js. If  I render a html page with a nvd3 chart, there is some html code that seems something like this:

[svg] ... image properties ... [/svg]

If a save that part of the code, and open as a svg file the chart lacks of the nvd3 styles. At first I thought about adding nvd3.css styles within the just saved svg file or as an external css file. But it seems that styles aren't applied to the svg chart neither.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/07/export-image-from-d3js-page-as-svg-or.html)?

Comment: Thank you Lars, I'll give a try on SVG Crowbar.